# Passing a struct data to a variable C++?

Tags: c++, math, data-structures, struct, fractions

first I'd like to apologize for my bad English and thank you in advance for reading and helping.

Basically I have two structs that hold 3 ints:
numbers
fractionAnswers

I then have a class called *addSubFractions* that takes two *numbers* struct type as parameters and returns a fractionAnswers struct type. My goal is to assign the return from the *addSubFractions* class to a *numbers* type struct variable called *answers*.

I am fairly new to C++ and I thought that I would be able to do this logically, I googled as much as I could without any good info.

Heres a part of the code that is not working for me:

```
int main() {
numbers first, second, answer ;

cout << "Enter fraction" ;
cin >> first.wholeNumber ;
cin >> first.numerator   ;
cin >> first.denominator ;
cout << "Enter second fraction" ;
cin >> second.wholeNumber ;
cin >> second.numerator ;
cin >> second.denominator ;


answer = addSubFractions(first, second) ;

cout << "Your answer is:" <<  answer.numerator << "/" << answer.denominator ;

return 0 ;}
```

Here is the other class I was talking about

```
    fractionAnswers addSubFractions(numbers firstFraction, numbers secondFraction) {
    numbers answerFraction, holdFraction1, holdFraction2      ;
    fractionAnswers someAnswers               ;

    //Multiply to get same denominator
    holdFraction1.denominator   =   firstFraction.denominator   *   secondFraction.denominator ;
    holdFraction2.denominator   =   firstFraction.denominator   *   secondFraction.denominator ;

    //Numerator multiplication to match new denominator
    holdFraction1.numerator     =   firstFraction.numerator     *   secondFraction.denominator ;
    holdFraction2.numerator     =   secondFraction.numerator    *   firstFraction.denominator  ;


    //Reduce fractions first
    while (true) {
        if(!reduceFractions(holdFraction1))
            break;
    }

    //Reduce fractions second
        while (true) {
            if(!reduceFractions(holdFraction2))
                break;
        }

        someAnswers.numeratorAns     =   holdFraction1.numerator + holdFraction2.numerator ;
        someAnswers.denominatorAns   =   holdFraction2.denominator                  ;
return someAnswers ;
}
```

this is reduceFractions

```
bool reduceFractions(numbers Fractions) {
    bool answer ;

    for (int i = Fractions.numerator ; i >= 2 ; i--) {       //This will keep running until i = the GFC for both numerator & denominator
        if ((((Fractions.numerator % i) == 0) && (Fractions.denominator % i) == 0)) {

            Fractions.numerator     /=   i ;
            Fractions.denominator   /=   i ;
            answer                   =   true ;
        }
    }

    answer   =   false ;
    return answer ;

}
```

These are the structs

```
struct numbers {
    int numerator   ;
    int denominator ;
    int wholeNumber ;
};

struct fractionAnswers {
    int numeratorAns   ;
    int denominatorAns ;
    int wholeNumberAns ;
};
```

Comment: You're returning a value of type `fractionAnswers` from your function and trying to assign it to a value of type `numbers` in `main()`. That is probably not what you intended to do.

Comment: What is the definition of `reduceFractions`?  Also, it might make more sense to call it on `someAnswers` after you've filled it with values, and `someAnswers` should probably be a `numbers`, not its own type (and the function should return the appropriate type).

Comment: you can also just do `while(reduceFactions(....)){}`, no need for the inner `if` + `break`.

Comment: I'll add the definition right now @Namfuak. And yeah I understand what you mean, I just wanted to be little organized

Comment: But in general, without seeing the defintions of `numbers` and `fractionAnswers`, it's hard to diagnose anything.

Comment: Adding extra classes that don't provide extra functionality is the opposite of organized....

Comment: Well, for one, `reduceFactions(numbers Fractions)` is pass-by-value, meaning it's copying the input, not modifying it in place. So it's not actually doing anything, and if the GCF takes more than one pass will never actually break your while-loop. You need to do `reduceFractions(numbers& Fractions)` instead to get pass-by-reference. See [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/71-function-parameters-and-arguments/) for more on C++'s pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value vs. pass-by-pointer symantics.

Comment: I got rid of the fractionAnswers as adviced and made it all numbers. Thank you for that @aruisdante .

Comment: I suggest you overload the following operators in your fractions class:  `operator+`, `operator>>`, `operator<<` and `operator+=`.  By placing the functions inside your structure, you can minimize the need to pass variables.

Comment: what do you mean? What would I overload the insertion operator for? @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code shouldn't compile, is that correct? You can't assign a value of type `fractionAnswers` to a variable of type `numbers`, even though they have the same layout of members. Some options are:

- Change the return type of `addSubFractions` to `numbers`.
- Change `answer = addSubFractions(first, second) ;` to `fractionAnswers temp = addSubFractions(first, second); answer.numerator = temp.numeratorAns; answer.denominator = temp.denominatorAns; answer.wholeNumber = temp.wholeNumberAns;`

Comment: There are a whole lot more problems than just the return type in the code.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I thought that since they had the same layout members it would be ok. It works now! And thanks @aruisdante for that link and for informing me about the & operator.